# Proper ECS (Unity) Buff/Debuff system structure problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, buffer, entity

Modifier = Buff/Debuff

I'm currently jumping ship with my project from OOP to ECS. And want to change the old [abstract decorate pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to a new faster ECS one.

How the current system works: Base abstract class `Modifier` has an Update function that the modifiers use to update their timers/apply over time effects, etc.
And there's simple modifier classes like `AttackSpeedModifier` that implement `Modifier` and only care about the values they use & how they use them. Like this:

```
protected override void ApplyEffect()
{
    Target.AttackSpeed += Value;
}
```

I'm struggeling to find a proper ECS buff/debuff implementation with only using structs (value types). My current thoughts/approach are such:

1. Make a seperate component for each buff:

```
public struct ExampleFireAttackBuff : IComponentData
{
    public float Damage;
    public float Cooldown;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that every modifier would need its own seperate system, & that would produce a lot of code duplication. And removing component every time the effect is done is also less than ideal.

2. Or make a buffer of buff/debuffs and have a "master" element:

```
public struct ModifierElement : IBufferElementData
{
    public ModifierType ModifierType;
    public float Value1;
    public float Value2;
    public float Value3;
    public float Duration;
    public bool IsStackable; 
    etc...
}
```

The problem with the second approach is that I would need to implement functionality based on "ModifierType" or some other way. Instead of overriding base class. And there would be a lot of redundant data. A simple permanent speed buff would only use 3-4 variables, while the close struct would have much more because all other modifiers need them.

Am I missing something, and/or is there a better way of making such an elaborate system? I'm not really happy with either of them currently.
There's also a "ComboModifier" that triggers on specific sets of modifiers, but that's a topic for another day/another thought.